# How can I set a dashboard provisioned via API as default dashboard for an org in Grafana?

Tags: grafana

We run a stateless Grafana in k8s. It's deployed with the [Grafana operator](https://github.com/grafana-operator/grafana-operator).

We have a dashboard that's also deployed using that very operator. Now I want this dashboard as a default for my Org (Default Main Org.).

The config allows setting a default dashboard, but [you need to provide a filesystem location](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/administration/organization-preferences/#use-a-json-file-as-the-home-dashboard).

I did not find the dashboard on the file system, I believe the operator provisions it using the API, so there is no file system location for this dashboard.

How is that possible? It seems that this can only be achieved using their [API](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/developers/http_api/preferences/#update-current-org-prefs); this makes things pretty complicated. Isn't there any other way, ideally declarative?